# Case sensitive match using python re.search

Tags: python, regex

I want to do a case sensitive match from the text. In the below case i tried matching the "Ca.iNy" using re.search, I want to match where "C" should be in upper case and rest all characters might be in any of the cases. If it matches the case i want set a value to a variable.

I have taken the help form SO and implemented by checking whether the first letter is a capital or not and it worked fine for a single check.

```
s = "The details belong to (Ca.iNy.) in this case"
reg = re.compile("Ca.iny.", re.I)
reg.search(s).group().startswith("C").
```

However, I am not able to use it in an "if else loop". I tried the code below, but the search seems to be case-insensitive. Can anyone please let me?

```
import re

st = "The details belong to (Ca.iNy.) in this case"
Mval = ''

if re.search(r"C(?i)a.iny", st):
    Mval = "AAAAA"
elif re.search(r"(?i)Ky.", st):
    Mval = "BBBBB"
elif re.search(r"(?i)M.sa.", st):
    Mval = "CCCCC"
else:
    Mval = "DDDDD"

print Mval
```

Comment: @Wooble. The answer which is there deals with only a single case. But problem here is during implementing with if else loop. Because if need to match around 50 cases using if else. it will not be fine if i compile all the patterns initially.

Comment: @Wooble Can you please unmark from duplicate. so that any one of you can help me in implementing this?

Comment: `if`/`else` is a) **not a loop** and b) **not relevant to the problem**. The problem is that you have switched from using a compiled regex with a `search` method to calling the module's `re.search`. This can be addressed in two ways: by **using separate compiled regexes in each place**, according to the exact way that you **already found** to solve the problem; or by telling the `re.search` to work case-insensitively - it can be passed the same `re.I` flag; see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

st = "The details belong to (Ca.iNy.) in this case"
Mval = ''

if re.search(r"C""(?i)a.iny", st):
    Mval = "AAAAA"
elif re.search(r"(?i)Ky.", st):
    Mval = "BBBBB"
elif re.search(r"(?i)M.sa.", st):
    Mval = "CCCCC"
else:
    Mval = "DDDDD"

print Mval
```

Comment: This answer would be a bit more useful if you included a little text. Try explaining what you did to solve the problem, and why.

Comment: @jeff i did not get you . can you please let me know where i need to change in my code?

Comment: @BryanOakley can you help me implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
All = {"CA.ing": 3, "cA.aec": 10}
st = "The details belong to (Ca.inY.) in this case"
Mval = ''
class1 = r"[a-z][a-z].[a-z][a-z][a-z]"
class2 = r"[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]"  # For strings like alaska

if re.search(class1, st, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    found_value = re.search(class1, flags=re.IGNORECASE).group()
    if found_value in All.keys():
        Mval = All[found_value]
elif re.search(class2, st):
    found_value = re.search(class2, st).group()
    if found_value in All.keys():
        Mval = All[found_value]

#This will return a KeyError if a string is present not in your dictionary
#Note : You can take care of the different case sensitive cases in the dictionary, by
# only including the proper cases
```

Comment: Is it possible to divide the expected groups into classifications?

Comment: like, some are 6 chars long, some have a "." separator"? This will help you to not need a crazy long list of if/else statements

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answers and help. i hope its difficult to have an expected group classification.

Comment: Ok well, just suppose you were able to, I will upload one more answer that might help, with comments nearby that should help, and as a note, it is very important which cases are meant for case sensitivity and which are not

Comment: This should work i guess. i will let you know i case i need any help further. once again thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mport re

reg = re.compile('([a-z]{2})\.[a-z]{3}',re.I)

def code(X,r):
    for ma in r.finditer(X):
        if ma.group(1)[0].upper()==ma.group(1)[0]:
            GV = 'OK'
        else:
            GV = '- bad match -'
        yield '  {!s:10}  {!s:^13}'.format(ma.group(), GV)

data = ('Ca.imo  Ca.IMo gggg Ca.iMo   CL.icv   cl.icv  cL.icv'
        'hhhh  ca.ghc  Rl.axp  bbb  Rl.AXp  nm.fgt')

print '\n'.join(res for res in code(data,reg))
```

result

```
  Ca.imo           OK      
  Ca.IMo           OK      
  Ca.iMo           OK      
  CL.icv           OK      
  cl.icv      - bad match -
  cL.icv      - bad match -
  ca.ghc      - bad match -
  Rl.axp           OK      
  Rl.AXp           OK      
  nm.fgt      - bad match -
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

st = "The details belong to (Ca.iNy.) in this case"
Mval = ''

if re.search(r"C[a-z].[a-z][a-z]", st):   # Only change
    Mval = "AAAAA"
elif re.search(r"(?i)Ky.", st):
    Mval = "BBBBB"
elif re.search(r"(?i)M.sa.", st):
    Mval = "CCCCC"
else:
    Mval = "DDDDD"

print Mval
```

Comment: This answer would be a bit more useful if you included a little text. Try explaining what you did to solve the problem, and why.

Comment: Sorry about that, the one with no comment was an accidental post.

Comment: This one, only has the [a-z].[a-z][a-z] placed instead of r"C""(?i)a.iny", st)         , for readability, and to make the following letters lower-case

Comment: It is primitive, but the search moves on to the else at the end.

Comment: @user2112190 But consider a case where if it matches "Ca.iRo." i need to set Mval to "DDDDD" and if matched "Ca.IPl Vn.Lp" . i need to set Mval to "FFFFF" i  need to keep such conditions around 50.

Comment: sorry i keep pressing enter.                                            if re.search(#pattern#):                                                   ....if re.search(#pattern#).match() in dictionary.keys():               ........Mval = dictionary[re.search(#pattern#).match()]               # In other words, a dictionary with strings as keys and mvals as values, you would only need one if statement

Comment: @user2112190 My point is how can we do a case sensitive match in re.search? like "Ca.iNy" and "ca.iNy" are different. think suppose case i want to match a sentence "Freedom FIGHTER" where first word "F" is capital and the secondword is totally capital.

Comment: the beginning of the page implied that you are always expecting the start of the string to be "C", is that not the case? the current loop ensures that only a string with a capital C is matched.

Comment: @user2112190 I have many such cases for example: Ca.imo, CL.icv, Ca.ghc, Rl.axp, Nm.fgt, ....... if it matches Ca.imo i want to set to "aaaa" if it matches "CL.icv" i want to set to "bbbb"

Comment: to be more precise, here is what could work, STEP 1, use a re.search to return string with "Ca." at the start. STEP 2, search dictionary keys for all expected strings. STEP 3, if matched value is a key, set "mval" equal to the dictionary value

Comment: Well for something like this, there must be a unifying quality, here, it seems they are all 6 characters long with 2 letters in front, a ".", and three more letters

Comment: if that is the case, I will post one more answer which you may find helpful. Are all expected strings of that form?

Comment: @user2112190 no not really . there is a case where i need to match a word something like this "Alaska" where "A" should be capital